# The reached percentage of privileges are shown in a new line

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The reached percentage for the "remove new user restrictions" privilege is show on a new line.

In some sites, for example drupal.stackexchange.com, that happens also when the privilege page being viewed is not for that privilege.

[image: screenshot]

In other sites, for example programmers.stackexchange.com judaism.stackexchange.com (a beta site), that happens when viewing that privilege page.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

I am using Safari 5.1.2 running on Mac OS X 10.7.2.

Comment: Repeated on Chrome 16 / Windows XP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This bug has been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124028/153008) with the roll out of the [new theme for beta sites](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/).

Comment: Isn't that true for beta sites? Only beta sites use the new theme. In my question I am referring to both beta, and graduated sites (such as _Drupal Answers_).

Comment: I don't see the issue on _Drupal Answers_ anymore; I guess the fix is valid for all the sites.

Comment: @kia: Yes, it would only be true for beta sites. I didn't realize that Drupal wasn't in beta (and looking at it now, it's actually quite beautiful; too bad I don't know anything about Drupal!). It does appear that they've reduced the font size slightly, though, so I guess that has made the problem disappear.

Comment: @TheEstablishment, this still occurs for me on SO and meta (didn't check other sites), on my copy of Firefox 12.0 running on ArchLinux, viewed on a reasonably wide desktop screen.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the Font Size setting in Chrome options --> Under the Hood is set to *Large*. Guess Safari has similar settings?

The container element (`sidebar`) has fixed width that is simply not enough, so the text has to wrap over two lines.

I don't think it's really a bug and can't see any reasonable solution as the sidebar is floating so relative width (in percentage) probably won't really work.

Anyway, using *Medium* font size makes it look nice and dandy.

Comment: I changed the font size, in Safari, but that didn't have any effect on how the privilege page is rendered.

Comment: Maybe it render stuff differently. Can you test on Chrome?

Comment: Actually, I don't have the same issue, with Google Chrome 17.0.963.79 and an unregistered account.

Answer (score -1):

If number and text are sorted in reverse order, the layout is more simple to do, because the first column is of 2-4 chars width:

```
  7% low
 90% Revolution number nine 
100% foobar bar baz bazzabar
100% vote up
100% vote down
```