# Privileges progress report misalignment

Tags: bug, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The reached percentage of privileges are shown in a new line](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119565/the-reached-percentage-of-privileges-are-shown-in-a-new-line)

When I look up the thresholds for [Christianity.SE privileges](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit), I see this misaligned text:

[image]

It seems there's not quite enough room for the `100%` text when the privilege description is long.  I'm using Google Chrome, if it matters.

Comment: @Cody: That image looks familiar... ;-)  Have you tried it somewhere that you have lots of reputation to get you over 100%?  At 96%, "access to moderator tools" looks just fine.  In a few days, I bet it will be misaligned.

Comment: Whoops! Not only did I link the wrong image, I failed to notice that you had 100% and I only had 10%. That's precisely what is pushing you over the edge. I see the same thing on the Philosophy beta site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're in the process of rolling out a new theme to the beta sites, starting with [Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit).

This bug has been fixed there:

[image]