# Alignment issues on privileges page

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, privileges-page

The percentages are improperly aligned for me on the [Privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges), as seen below. It only happens with 3 or 4 of them because they are too long.

If the sidebar were about 15px wider and the mainbar 15px thinner, the issue would go away.

I'm using Chromium 25.0.1364.172 on Linux.

<sup>Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67609/text-sometimes-overflows-margin-in-privileges-section?lq=1, though that question refers to a specific item that only overflows when you click on it.</sup>

[image]

Comment: What browser/OS?

Comment: possible duplicate of "Misaligned table on privileges page" __EDIT: NOT A DUPE, SEE BELOW__

Comment: nope since that question is IE7 and this is Chromium 25.

Comment: why does that duplicate box appear with just one close vote? or is it only there for me?

Comment: Wow, I read it twice and still never saw the line where you said "Chromium." Sorry.

Comment: I inserted that after the comment.

Comment: Oh, okay then. Thanks for not having me look and feel stupid forever.

Comment: @JakobWeisblat: Only you see it.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha when will it go away?

Comment: @JakobWeisblat: When the close vote expires, should take a few days.

Comment: This has happened before: [The reached percentage of privileges are shown in a new line](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119565/the-reached-percentage-of-privileges-are-shown-in-a-new-line), and [Privileges progress report misalignment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124010)

Comment: But all of those questions refer to beta sites, which have been fixed. This happens on SO.