# Why doesn't accepting a CW answer for a not CW question give reputation?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, community-wiki

I am not calling for a change; still, I am interested to understand if what happens makes sense.

I have accepted an answer for [The reached percentage of privileges are shown in a new line](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119565/the-reached-percentage-of-privileges-are-shown-in-a-new-line); because the answer is a CW, I didn't get any reputation for accepting it.
The question is not a CW; the accepted answer is a CW, while the other answers are not CW. Is there any difference between accepting a not CW answer, and accepting a CW answer that would justify not getting reputation in the latter case?

Also, the person who wrote the answer doesn't get any reputation, but in that case it could be what they want. I think that a user who took the time for answering, and giving the correct answer, would deserve the reputation for having the answer accepted, but I can understand if they prefer not getting any reputation at all.

Comment: Do you mean the other *answers* are not CW?

Comment: Well, the technical explanation would probably be that votes on CW posts don't have an impact on anyone's reputation, and accepting an answer is an `AcceptedByOriginator` vote.

Comment: @lunboks That would explain why who wrote the answer doesn't get any reputation. I can understand the technical reason; what I am asking is if that is what it should happen.

Comment: @AnnaLear Yes, that is what I meant. `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought about it as well for some time. Here is one paragraph from the excellent blog post
[The Future of Community Wiki](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/):

> The intent of community wiki in answers is to help share the burden of solving a question. An incomplete “seed” answer is a stepping stone to a complete solution **with help from others**; an incomplete question is a hindrance and an obstacle to getting a solution as no one understands the inquiry. It is in answers that the goal of community wiki, for the community, by the community, shows its truest colors.

Bold part is my own doing - this leads me to believe that when user mark his/her own answer as community wiki it means: "I might be the first to answer, but expect others to fill in the gaps, so I don't deserve the reputation".

So, I don't think the author of the CW answer should get any points when it's accepted however can't see any reason why the question author won't get the +2 bonus - unless of course the question itself is CW as well.

Comment: OK, but if the answer is the one that was most helpful in solving the problem, it probably still deserves the checkmark and the 15 rep.

Comment: @Robert but if the answer is given by number of users, the reputation should be equally divided among them to be fair.

Comment: Which is probably why no reputation is awarded at all.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd That is not always the case: There are CW answers where a single user wrote most of the answer, if not all the answer. I think it's relevant who wrote the answer in the moment the answer is accepted, not who will edit the answer in future.

Comment: @kiamlaluno still, I don't think this justifies giving the rep to the CW author - if one think his answer is complete or nearly complete, why mark it as CW in the first place?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd The fact the CW author thinks the answer is not complete doesn't mean it is not complete. The fact the question's author accepts the answer should mean that for that user the answer is complete, which means it answers what the question's author asked. It could make sense not to give reputation for the accepted answer to the user who wrote it when the answer has been edited from another user before it gets accepted, or remove that reputation when the answer has been edited between X days (and probably not before X hours since the answer has been accepted).