# Give the +2 reputation bonus for accepting answers also for CW answers

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, community-wiki

Accepting a community wiki answer to a non-CW question does not result in 2 additional reputation points for the accepting user, as it would for accepting a normal answer (see e.g. [Why doesn't accepting a CW answer for a not CW question give reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126381/why-doesnt-accepting-a-cw-answer-for-a-not-cw-question-give-reputation) and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5000/cw-answers-considered-harmful).

I don't see any reason to handle CW answers any different that other answers in this regard. The idea behind the acceptance bonus doesn't change for CW answers, there is no reason to deny users the bonus here.

There might be some borderline cases when the accepting user also participated in the CW answer. If he created the CW answer, he should not get the bonus, but in all other cases I think the acceptance bonus should still be payed out.

Comment: I retagged this as `discussion` from `feature-request`. I'd like to see some discussion on this. Occasionally, [as here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098319/delete-from-table-when-field-does-not-match-another-table-in-mysql) I will CW a syntax error answer while CV'ing too localized if it seems like the answer is better spelled out in the Answers than just a little comment.  It never occurred to me before now to find out if I'm depriving the OP of 2rep because I don't think the answer's worthy of a rep gain.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with this. As is posted here [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) People are encouraged to select answers and part of that encouragement is the +2 points.

Also as a frequent user of SO it saves me a lot of time, (and is just easier to process) when I click on a question and it has an accepted answer. I'm sure everyone has been in a position where we click a question see 10 answers and none of them are accepted (it's rather annoying).

So to me as a end user trying to find info I don't care if the answer is a CW or not, I care far more about whether the answer fixed the problem. Which means anything that encourages users to accept *helpful (again see above link for helpful definition)* answers, is a positive for the QA format here on SE.